# as goes the country

Tags: meaning, as

Can one say:

a. As goes the country, so goes the world.

b. As behaves the father, so behaves the son.

Can (a) be used to mean: We are losing the country and the world?

Can it be used to mean: The state the country is in reflects the state
the world is in?

Comment: An idiom covering (b) is "[Like father, like son](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Like+Father+Like+Son)". I haven't heard (a). Is it supposed to mean the same thing, or that what is happening in a particular country is *indicative* of the rest of the world?

Comment: They are grammatical, but sound very stilted and old-fashioned. We don't use these inverted forms in ordinary speech today. It would be more natural to say something like  "As the country is going, so is the world going."

Comment: Often, but not always, 'As first thing so second thing' means that the first thing causes or inspires the second thing.

Comment: Thank you all so much. I think in the US there's a saying: As goes 'name of State' so goes the country. I think the name of the State is usually Maine, but might change. I think the idea is that Maine reflects the situation of the whole country. It indicates what is happening in the country. Not sure of what I am saying. I thought the construct must be well-known, but apparently it is archaic.

Comment: It is probably less archaic to say 'As Maine goes, so goes the country'. Also what constitutes an 'archaic' construct can vary by e.g. location (US vs UK), age and educational level of speaker. Some people think everything before text-speak is archaic.